# VB .NET Can Select on Linked Server but cannot update

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I've added a linked server by using Management Studio.

In vb.net I can SELECT but I can't UPDATE

I get a timeout error even if I set the timeout to 4 minutes.
Here the code:

```
Dim cnx As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
cnx.ConnectionString = "server=MY_LOCAL_SERVER;Trusted_Connection=yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
cnx.Open()

' This is working'
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = cnx.CreateCommand
cnx.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [MY_LINKED_SERVER].[MYDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE]"
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

' This is not working :( '
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [MY_LINKED_SERVER].[MYDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE] SET Foo = @foo WHERE id = @id"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foo", "bar")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "10")
cmd.CommandTimeout = 240
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ' Timeout exception
```

If I execute this update query in Sql Management Studio it's working.

EDIT: When i execute the query FROM SSMS it is very quick

EDIT: INSERT or DELETE are working. Only UPDATE make a timeout error ...

EDIT: It seems that if i'm not using Parameters in my update query, it's working, eg: "UPDATE ... SET Foo = 'bar'" will work while "UPDATE ... SET Foo = @foo" won't work Oo

Comment: Are you sure something else isn't holding the row lock or transaction open?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: what if you run the sql code using SSMS on your local server?

Comment: @Mort yes i'm sure. The linked server DB is a test database, i'm alone on it

Comment: @RogerWolf Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: @Paolo The sql work well from SSMS

Comment: what's the amount of data? how long does it takes for the command to execute when run in ssms? please update the question; don't add details in the comments.

Comment: Can you update any tables via code? How about deletes or inserts? Even if you are the only person on the database, your SMS session could be row locking while your app tries to update.